# Can't Find Project or Library - VB6

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I have an old vb6 system, which I tried to run again. It throws an error saying    `Can't Find Project or Library` in the line of code below.

```
Dim db As Database
```

I was thingking, it has to do with uncheck references. How will I fix this? Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Most likely, `Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library`. Try adding it from Project>References, and check if you still get this error.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I already have checked that reference. What else should I do?

Comment: Okay, open "Project -> References" again, look at the ticked items to see if any of them starts with "MISSING:".

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed -> Microsoft Development Environment 10.0 is missing. What shall I do?

Comment: Well, you probably don't need that reference in your project. If that's the case, simply uncheck that reference and try to run the program. However, If you do know that this is a reference you use in your project, you have two options: 1. Using another version (e.g. 9.0). 2. If you need a specific version, then you'll need to locate/install the related library.

Comment: @Qerjiuthn: open in Notepad the project, form or module where the error is thrown, there you will find all the referenced objects. The GUID of the objects will tell us exactly what is needed by each form/module.